# Flow Layout in flutter example

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

i want to implement flow layout in flutter i found a class called FLOW in sdk but unable to find sample code on how to use it

here is the layout i am trying to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [`Wrap`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) instead of `Flow`.

`Flow` is for more complicated custom layout. `Wrap` is what is used to achieve the layout in your screenshot.

```
Wrap(
  spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
  runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
  children: <Widget>[
      Chip(
        avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: Text('AH')),
        label: Text('Hamilton'),
      ),
      Chip(
        avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: Text('ML')),
        label: Text('Lafayette'),
      ),
      Chip(
        avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: Text('HM')),
        label: Text('Mulligan'),
      ),
      Chip(
        avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: Text('JL')),
        label: Text('Laurens'),
      ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: oh that's great but how can i achieve something when i click the FAB it added a chip dynamically

Comment: That's another question sir. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In Flutter wrap is batter widget for creating layout like your screenshot

**Wrap** : It can adjust its children according to the space available to it on the Screen. The default arrangement is horizontal (like a row) but you can make it vertical (like a column).
**chip** : This widget use for create TAG or chips

```
new Wrap(
  spacing: 5.0, // horizontal gap between chips
  runSpacing: 2.0, // gap between row
  children: <Widget>[
      new Chip(
        label: new Text('One'),
      ),
      new Chip(
        label: new Text('Two'),
      ),
      new Chip(
       label: new Text('Three'),
      ),
      new Chip(
        label: new Text('Four'),
      ),
  ],
)
```